# not able to change MS Access password

Tags: ms-access, change-password

I have an MS Access database. I do not know why I am not able to change the password. I open the database in exclusive and then enter the password to open the database. When I click the file, the info only has  Compact & Repair and Encrypt with Password.  When I click the Encrypt with Password and enter the password, it already says 'Invalid password'.   I am also not able to remove the password since there is no item for it.   When I open a blank database and try to remove the password, it is ok since there is an icon and text to show to remove the password.  Could anyone help me to correct this? why like this.

Comment: When I open encrypted db as exclusive, I get `Decrypt Database` in Options, not Encrypt. To change password I first Decrypt then I can Encrypt with new password.

Comment: This link might help: [Cannot Remove Password From Accdb Database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3992622b-22d6-480b-9774-1e2554d8cffe/cannot-remove-password-from-accdb-database)

Comment: Thanks, Rene. The method in the link worked for my problem. I have created a customized button so Ribbon Name in the Access option is not empty. Maybe this caused the problem as said.